# Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i got a problem when i try my html.
and when i see on web element i got this error
"Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined"

this is my app.js

```
    angular.module('underscore', [])
    .factory('_', function() {
      return window._; // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
    });

    // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
    // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
    // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
    angular.module('your_app_name', [
      'ionic',
      'angularMoment',
      'your_app_name.controllers',
      'your_app_name.directives',
      'your_app_name.filters',
      'your_app_name.services',
      'your_app_name.factories',
      'your_app_name.config',
      'your_app_name.views',
      'underscore',
      'ngMap',
      'ngResource',
      'ngCordova',
      'slugifier',
      'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards',
      'youtube-embed'
    ])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform, PushNotificationsService, $rootScope, $ionicConfig, $timeout) {

      $ionicPlatform.on("deviceready", function(){
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        PushNotificationsService.register();
      });

      // This fixes transitions for transparent background views
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if(toState.name.indexOf('auth.walkthrough') > -1)
        {
          // set transitions to android to avoid weird visual effect in the walkthrough transitions
          $timeout(function(){
            $ionicConfig.views.transition('android');
            $ionicConfig.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
            console.log("setting transition to android and disabling swipe back");
          }, 0);
        }
      });
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if(toState.name.indexOf('app.feeds-categories') > -1)
        {
          // Restore platform default transition. We are just hardcoding android transitions to auth views.
          $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
          // If it's ios, then enable swipe back again
          if(ionic.Platform.isIOS())
          {
            $ionicConfig.views.swipeBackEnabled(true);
          }
            console.log("enabling swipe back and restoring transition to platform default", $ionicConfig.views.transition());
        }
      });

      $ionicPlatform.on("resume", function(){
        PushNotificationsService.register();
      });

    })


    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
      $stateProvider
.state('head', {
      url: "/head",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "views/app/head.html",
      controller: 'HeadCtrl'
  })

  .state('head.merchantlist', {
      url: "/merchantslist",
      views: {
          'merchantsmenuContent': {
              templateUrl: "views/app/merchant/merchantspec-list.html",
              controller: "MerchantlistCtrl"
          }
      }
  })
;

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/head/merchantslist');
});
```

this is my controller.js

```
angular.module('your_app_name.controllers', [])

.controller('HeadCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicConfig) {

})
.controller('MerchantlistCtrl', function ($scope) {

})
```

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-contrib-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-slugify/dist/angular-slugify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-contrib-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-youtube-mb/dist/angular-youtube-embed.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/factories.js"></script>
    <script src="js/views.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="your_app_name">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my head.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar app-top-bar">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
<ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="merchantsmenuContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

and this is my merchants

```
<ion-view class="merchantspec-view">
    <ion-nav-title>
        <span>Restaurants</span>
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem.

my `<ion-nav-bar>` in head.html doesn't have a close
i forgot "/" on second `<ion-nav-bar>`